# Firebase Cloud Functions: "4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We're getting this error when trying to add data to firestore using cloud functions.

We're getting data from an API and it works fine, but on adding the data to firestore it produces this error,

```
Error detected in fetchInventory {"exceptionInfo":{"type":"Error","message":"4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded"},"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.clouderrorreporting.v1beta1.Insight","errorGroup":"CJ69k8PhgvTNKQ","errorEvent":{"serviceContext":{"resourceType":"cloud_function","service":"fetchInventory"},"message":"Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded\n    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)\n    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:179:52)\n    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:336:141)\n    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:299:181)\n    at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:145:78\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)","eventTime":"2021-05-23T10:11:12.748Z"}}
```

**We're writing around 900 documents in firestore.**

A detailed explanation of the issue would help a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error can be caused by writing to much data to `firestore` at once. The error also apperas sometimes on bad internet connections or bugs in the code.

Try to reduce your write to not more than 500 elements or even less.
If that doesn't help check if you have a slow connection.
If you still see that error I would ask you to share some of your code so we can check that to.

[image]

Yout can find more about the limits [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).

Comment: The same code works absolutely fine on firebase emulator on pc, but fails to write to firestore when deployed...

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of writes in a specific time?

Comment: Don't these limits apply to emulators?

Comment: thanks for helping out, batch committing more than 500 commits was the issue.